# Rails - polymorphic associations with join models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been reading the Rails associations guides but I am still not sure if I am doing this correctly.

My app has Users and Products.

A User can contribute comments, reviews, and photos for those Products.

I figured that I would make a join model called Contributions:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :building
  belongs_to :contributable, polymorphic: true
```

And then for User:

```
has_many :contributions, as: contributable
has_many :products, through: contributions
```

Products:

```
has_many :contributions, as: contributable
has_many :users, through: contributions
```

And then for example, in my Review model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
```

I don't feel like I am doing this right. Basically, I want a Contribution to always have an associated Product and User, but want contributions to be able to include either a Review, Comment, or Photo.

Is a join table with polymorphic associations the right way to go here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this is what you're looking for.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contributions
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contributions
end

class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :contributable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contribution, :as => :contributable
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contribution, :as => :contributable
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contribution, :as => :contributable
end
```

Make sure to have the `contributable_id` and `contributable_type` fields in your `contributions` table.

Comment: Got it thanks! Do I need this type of join table and polymorphic association though? Could I also just do something like Product has_many :reviews, has_many :comments, etc and for Reviews to belongs_to :user and belongs_to :product?

Comment: It might depend on how many of these types your application will use. For example, as you add more and more, `Product` can end up with more uses of `has_many` macros than you'd like. Another thing to consider is if you will be querying for a list of all three types often. Such as if you want a timeline. You can currently do `@product.contributions` and just sort them however you want. Otherwise, you would have to do `@product.reviews`, `@product.comments` and `@product.photos` and manually merge and sort them yourself. Still, his may actually be a good thing depending on your application.